# How to chain alias commands in cmder

Tags: bash, scripting, alias, chaining, cmder

I love using aliases on my ubuntu server for repeated commands as they're a huge timesaver and they're absolutely irreplaceable for me now.

I've been using **cmder** a lot recently on Windows as it is the best console replacement for windows that I know of. It is a wonderful piece of software and I have almost all the basic bash commands including aliases.

However, I cannot find a way to chain multiple alias commands. I've tried delving into doskey at this link [Microsoft DOSKEY](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/doskey.mspx?mfr=true) and the macros without any luck.

So, basically I want to create multiple aliases. For e.g.

```
    alias loginuser1='ssh -i ~/user1keyfile user1@$s'
    alias mynewcloudserver='901.801.701.601'
```

and want to be able to login by typing:

```
    loginuser1 mynewcloudserver
    loginuser5 mytestingcloudserver
```

I have currently tried this:

```
    loginuser1 mynewcloudserver
```

which produces this error:

```
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname mynewcloudserver: no address associated with name
```

I get that this is because it is probably looking in my hosts file for **mynewcloudserver** and is unable to find an entry. I am able to login by doing this instead:

```
    loginuser1 901.801.701.601
```

which brings us to my problem. I am unable to call one **alias** from another **alias**

I know the above might not be the best way to create those aliases, but I just want to understand the logic and how to chain aliases together in **cmder** which will open up a host of possibilities **pun intended**.

If anyone can help me out, that would be great.

Comment: Bash aliases are exclusively command prefix substitutions. Use a ssh alias instead for easy ssh access to hosts

Comment: While this is helpful, it does not answer my original question. Your comment is a solution only for my ssh needs. I'd want to be able to alias stuff together for other commands as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I've found is to create a `myscript.sh` file with the commands, and create an alias to call the file.

It may be helpful to include `wait` between commands if they need to finish before the next one runs.

The first time you run it, it may ask you which program to use.  Choose `Git for Windows`.